# Removing a range of values from a linked list

Tags: linked-list

I am trying to remove a node from a linked list if its value falls within a certain range (greater than or equal to low and less than or equal to high). This code only removes the first value found within the range.

```
public void removeData(E low, E high) {
    Node previousNode = root;
    Node deleteNode = previousNode.getNext();
    while (deleteNode != null) {
        if (deleteNode.getValue().compareTo(low) >= 0 && deleteNode.getValue().compareTo(high) <= 0) {
            previousNode.setNext(deleteNode.getNext());
        }
        previousNode = previousNode.getNext();
        deleteNode = deleteNode.getNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code what you need to do is:

```
public void removeData(E low, E high) {
Node previousNode = root;
Node deleteNode = previousNode.getNext();
while (deleteNode != null) {
    if (deleteNode.getValue().compareTo(low) >= 0 && deleteNode.getValue().compareTo(high) <= 0) {
        previousNode.setNext(deleteNode.getNext());
    }else{
        previousNode = previousNode.getNext();
    }
    deleteNode = deleteNode.getNext();
}
```

}

because if one node is deleted the previous node doesn't need to incremented just deleteNode has to. and check for another deleteNode.

Hope this may help you.
Thanks!!